# Rewriting a loop with Rccp

Tags: r

I am a novice `Rcpp` user. I want to fasten my `for loop` which uses several entities from `r` environment, and updates two vectors through iterations.
The problem is that this is my first time facing `c` or `c++` so I do not understand how to write `rcpp` with `inline` packages.
Here is the reproducible loop that I want to rewrite.

```
rsi <- c(NaN, 0, 0, 9.2, 28, 11, 9, 8, 38, 27, 62, 57,59,67, 76, 68, 69, 49)
L <- 2
o <- 2
T_min <-100
T_m <- 0
# Predefine two vectors for results to be written in

rsi_u <- rep(0, length(rsi))
rsi_d <- rep(0, length(rsi))

# Set range of for loop to be apllied on
st <- L + 1 # L and o is some param fron environment
en <- length(rsi) - o - 2
for (i in st:en) {
  k <- i - o + 1
  k1 <- i - L + 1
  if (sum(rsi_u[k:i]) == 0 & sum(rsi_d[k:i]) == 0) {
    if (min(rsi[k1:i]) == rsi[i] & rsi[i] < T_min) {
      rsi_d[i] <- 1
    }
    if (max(rsi[k1:i]) == rsi[i] & rsi[i] > T_m) {
      rsi_u[i] <- 1
    }
  }
}
```

So as you can see there are loop which checks first condition

```
if (sum(rsi_u[k:i]) == 0 & sum(rsi_d[k:i]) == 0)
```

and then checks two other conditions. If one of the condition is `T`, then it writes `1L` to ith element of one of two predefined vecs. In addition each iteration relies on result of previous iterations.

The result of this loop is two vecs: `rsi_u` and `rsi_d`

In order to speed up this loop I decided to rewrite it with `rccp` and `inline`.
This is what I ended up with:

```
library("Rcpp")
library("inline")
loop_c <- cxxfunction(signature(k = "numeric", L = "numeric", 
en = "numeric", rsi = "numeric", o = "numeric", T_min = "numeric", T_m  ="numeric"), 
plugin = "Rcpp", body = "
for (int i = L + 1; i <= en; i++) {
  k = i - o + 1
  k1 = i - L + 1
  if (accumulate(rsi_u.k(), rsi_u.i(), 0)=0 &&
      accumulate(rsi_d.k(), rsi_d.i(), 0)=0) {
    if (min_element(rsi.k1(), rsi.i()) = rsi.i() && rsi.i < T_min) {
      rsi_u.i = 1
    }
    if (max_element(rsi.k1(), rsi.i()) = rsi.i() && rsi.i > T_m) {
      rsi_d.i = 1
    }
  }
}
return ?")
```

So here is the questions:

1. How can I return to `R environment` vecs `rsi_u` and `rsi_d` in form of `data.frame` or `matrix` with 2 cols and `length(rsi)` rows?
2. May be this loop can be speeded up with other tools? I tried apply family, but it was slower.

Comment: `T_min` and `T_max` is missing. As a side note, `inline` is a old package that is not really needed anymore. You can use `cppFunction` or `sourceCpp` from `Rcpp` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How can I return to R environment vecs rsi_u and rsi_d in form of data.frame or matrix with 2 cols and length(rsi) rows?

Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve, but regardless you can rewrite your code in C++ using Rcpp and the sugar functions `sum`, `max` and `min`. The code is very similar to the R equivalent code. Some important things to be aware of is that C++ is type-strong, meaning `2` and `2.0` are different numbers, (equivalent to `2` and `2L` in R), and vectors are 0-indexed rather than 1-index as in R (eg: The first element of `NumericVector F(3)` is 0 and the last is 2, in R it would be 1 and 3). This can lead to some confusion but the remaining code is the same.

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
List fun(NumericVector rsi,
         double T_min, double T_m,
         R_xlen_t L, R_xlen_t o) {
  R_xlen_t n = rsi.size(),
    st = L + 1,
    en = n - o  - 2;
  NumericVector rsi_u(n), rsi_d(n);

  // Note subsets are 0 indexed, so add -1 to indices
  for(R_xlen_t i = st - 1; i < en; i++) {
    R_xlen_t k = i - o + 1;
    R_xlen_t k1 = i - L + 1;
    Range sr(k, i), mr(k1, i);
    //LogicalVector rsub = sum(rsi_u[sr]) == 0, rsdb = sum(rsi_d[sr]) == 0;
    if(sum(rsi_u[sr]) == 0 && sum(rsi_d[sr]) == 0){
      if(min(rsi[mr]) == rsi[i] && rsi[i] < T_min){
        rsi_d[i] = 1.0;
      }
      if(max(rsi[mr]) == rsi[i] && rsi[i] > T_m){
        rsi_u[i] = 1.0;
      }
    }
  }
  return DataFrame::create(Named("rsi_d") = rsi_d, Named("rsi_u") = rsi_u);
}
```

As a side note, the `inline` package is now-a-days completely redundant. Most (if not all?) of the functionality is encapsulated within the `Rcpp::cppFunction` and `Rcpp::sourceCpp` functions. The code above can be imported using either of the commands below:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction(
'
// copy code to here. Note the single " ' "! Needed if there are double quotes in your C++ code
')
# Alternative
sourceCpp(
file = # Insert file path to file with code here
# Alt:
# code = '
# // copy code to here. Note the single " ' "! Needed if there are double quotes in your C++ code
# '
)
```

And that's it.

## May be this loop can be speeded up with other tools? I tried apply family, but it was slower.

As for this part of your question, the main ideas you should be looking toward is **vectorizing** your code. In your example it is not immediately possible, as you are overwriting part of the `rsi_d` and `rsi_u` vectors used in your conditions within the loop. Using `*apply` is equivalent to using a `for-loop` and will not improve performance significantly.

Comment: As a side note: Remove the line `LogicalVector rsub = ...`. In my first version I assigned the value and then used the assigned value in the first `if`. In the version above I forgot to remove it.